# How can I set Visual Studio Code to open a specific extension panel on startup?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed an extension called `Project Manager` by `Alessandro Fragnani`, this extension enables me to easily switch between projects with a single click, What I want is for my `vs code` to open this extension on startup instead of opening the welcome page or the home page, I tried playing around with `settings.json` but it seems the startup valid values are only:

```
Valid values: "none", "welcomePage", "readme", "newUntitledFile", "welcomePageInEmptyWorkbench"
```

and I couldn't choose my extension, is there any solution ?

Comment: ask Fragnani to add a setting that it creates the Webview on activation

Comment: @rioV8 Not a bad idea but I was expecting vs code settings.json to accept a value like this:  "workbench.startupEditor": "projectManager"

Comment: VSC has no knowledge of the `projectManager`, you have to call a command to start the Webview

Comment: @rioV8 You are correct but each extension has a unique Identifier, vs code can and should easily use this information to open any extension the user deems useful on its startup

Comment: have a look at [Post startup hook](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=colas.post-startup-hook)